# Why is the slope during strain hardening smaller?

Tags: material-science

[image]

During strain hardening, the slope on the stress-strain curve is smaller than during the elastic region. So why is it strain *hardening*, if during this region less stress is required for more strain?

Comment: These things are often not intuitive to me as well. For example, Young's Modulus, $E$, is called the modulus of elasticity. But the higher the value of $E$, the greater the stress needed to cause the same strain (the "stiffer" the material)..

Answer (score 1):

Because the material is able to resist *more* force without breaking, even if it is not getting stiffer. Compare this notion with that of strain-softening, where the maximum force (per unit area) that the material can resist is smaller than before the plastic strain.

Answer (score 1):

the elastic portion of the curve represents the resistance of the bonds between the metal atoms to being stretched. The different slope of the plastic region represents a different deformation mechanism, that of dislocation travel, pinning, climb, and (eventual) buildup and entanglement at grain boundaries, plus some grain rotation depending on the material being stretched.

(The permanent plastic deformation makes further dislocation movement increasingly difficult, which means that the sample acts harder and stronger than it did before the yield point. Remember that in the plastic region, if we reverse the strain and allow the sample to relax, it follows a straight line all the way back down to zero (paralleling the original linear elastic response). If we then resume pulling the sample, it follows that same straight line all the way up to the point where we stopped the test, indicating that the onset threshold of irreversible dislocation movement had been raised.)